# spark.driver.memory configuration is not being showed in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on spark in databricks.i want to adjust the configuration of spark.driver.memory.Since the default value is 1g  i want to increase to 14g because my driver has a total memory of 16 GB and i want to make the most of it. when i am querying this configuration using `spark.conf.get("spark.driver.memory"),` it gives error saying
 `"java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.driver.memory"`.
somewhere it was suggested that we need to use advanced options in the cluster to set this config. but i am curious to know why this is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver & executor memory are automatically tuned on Databricks, so you don't need to do it manually. Also, there are some limits on what maximum memory size could be set because Databricks needs additional memory for management tools - exact description [could be found in the following knowledge base article](https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/clusters/spark-shows-less-memory).  Approximate formula for executor memory is:

```
container_size = (vm_size * 0.97 - 4800MB)
spark.executor.memory = (0.8 * container_size)
```

For `spark.driver.memory` we need to account ~1Gb more memory compared to the executor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. spark is throwing java out of memory error for a 1gb file which i am trying to parse. the driver memory is around 64 GB.it is a binary file so i can see that only one partition is getting created..still the driver memory is huge. what can be done to rectify this?

Comment: it's heavily dependent on what is the file format, how do you read it, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex,,i will better put it as a separate question.